# Trying to access a public BigQuery set via Colabs. Keep getting create errors when trying to query public dataset

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I keep getting this error when trying to access one of the public datasets on BQ through Google Colabs:
**Access Denied: Project bigquery-public-data: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project bigquery-public-data.**

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
`project_id = 'bigquery-public-data'

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

%%bigquery --project bigquery-public-data
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as total_rows
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.gsod``
```

Anyone have any ideas on where to go? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hello @MikhailBerlyant Thanks for the help. Unfortunately: 

1. I'm not trying to create my own project. Ultimately, I need to be querying my company's projects where we do not have access to create jobs; just query existing tables. 
2. When I do so, it gives this error: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the project id variable you must specify in your code must be your own project, not the bigquery-public-data which is to be accessed from the query.